# Compile error - Using outputStream on Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Im new to Java and I'm having a little problem writing a series of random number to an output file. I need to used RandomAccessFile and writeDouble. Here is that pice of my code any idea why this is happening. Thanks

```
private static void numGenerator(int values){
    Random generator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < values; i++) {
        double number = generator.nextInt(200);
        System.out.println(number);
        String outFile = "output.txt";
        RandomAccessFile outputStream = null;
        try{
            outputStream = new RandomAccessFile(outFile,"rw");
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Error opening the file " + outFile);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        number = outputStream.writeDouble(number); //ERROR
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error makes sense. You're writing into a RAF, and per its [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) the writeDouble method returns void. Why are you trying to set a number equal to this? This statement makes no sense:

```
number = outputStream.writeDouble(number);
```

Instead just do:

```
outputStream.writeDouble(number);
```

Also, why create a new RAF with each iteration of the for loop? Don't you instead want to create one file before the for loop and add data to it inside of the loop?

Also, why use a RAF to begin with? Why not simply use a text file?

Comment: Im trying to get the random number im generating and copy them to the file

Comment: You're doing that with writeDouble.

Comment: But **it's not a text file.** It's a file of bytes. I'm guessing that you may be mistaken by using a random access file here.

Comment: @user1354275: to allow us to better help you, please tell us more about what your goal is and why you've decided on using a random access file (RAF) to store your data.

Answer (score 2):

Three things that jump out at me:

1. You're using `nextInt()` instead of `nextDouble()`.
2. Your IO operation isn't inside of the `try...catch` block.  Any call to any method that throws any exception *must* be inside of a `try...catch` block.  (Alternatively, if the method you're using has the signature `throws Exception`, then the `try...catch` block is unnecessary.  But somewhere, you'll need to handle the exception if/when it's thrown.)
3. [The return value of any of the write methods in `RandomAccessFile` are void.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html)  You won't be able to capture that in a variable.